# DOJO AJAX - How to change the whole JSP content?

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsp, dojo

I am using Dojo library. How can I replace all the content of my jsp/html content. I am trying to dynamically reload my page when a data is updated.

Here is my dojo code:

```
function reloadPage() {
 var thisUrl = '/CBS/a/customer/' + customerId + '/profile';

 dojo.xhrGet({
 url: thisUrl,
 load: function (data) {   
   document.body.innerHTML = data;
 },
 error: function (data, ioArgs){
   document.body.innerHTML  = "unknown error";
  }
 });
}
```

The server returns a complete html code including the html tags. The `data` variable holds all the html tags. In my code I did `document.body.innerHTML = data;`which is wrong because the content of body is replaced by a whole html page. It looks like ajax is working because its updated dynamically but my buttons are not working anymore. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use AJAX if you want  to update the **whole** page? Purpose of using of AJAX - update **part** of content(page), not updating the whole page. If you want to update the whole page, may be it will be more appropriate to use reload?

Comment: You mean I have to reload the whole page by clicking refresh or using submit instead of button?

Comment: It depends of your problem. When you want to update the content of page? You can do this, for example, when user click the button(then use submit).